# Why does my if function not return the proper value?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm quite new at Python programming so forgive me if it seems like a stupid question. This is my code with the given results:

Code:

```
def Stopping_Voltage(Frequency, Phi):
    x = (4.14E-15) * Frequency ##The value of (h/e) multiplied by frequency
    y = Phi / (1.602E-19) ##The value of Phi/e
    Energy = x * (1.602E-19)
    print(Energy)
    print(Phi)
    print(x)
    print(y)
    String = 'No electron is emitted'
    if Energy > Phi:
        Voltage = x - y
        return(Voltage)
    else:
        return(String)

Stopping_Voltage(10, (6.63228E-33))
```

Result:

```
6.632280000000001e-33
6.63228e-33
4.1400000000000005e-14
4.14e-14

6.310887241768095e-30
```

What we're asked to do is if the energy is less than or equal to phi, return the string but when testing it with the given variables, it should return the string but it is still giving me a quantitative result. I initially tried using "else" rather than "elif" but it still gave me the same thing (if that matters). When I printed the value for Energy and Phi, the energy value has a lot of zeroes after the decimal (with 1 following after all the zeroes). How do I fix this to give me the string?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please don't paste code as images. Copy the code here and create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can help you.

Comment: As @KarelTamayo says, images of code are not useful. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why they should be avoided. Code is written using a text editor, which means it can be easily copied and posted into your question here. Please [edit] to do so. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know. I've made the edits, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine! It does return the string, if `Energy` is <= `Phi`. It's just that your `Energy` in this particular example is really bigger than your `Phi` :) This is the [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) of a number, so `e` means 10^exponent like 2e-5 is equal to 2*10^-5. You can check it by adding `print(Energy > Phi)` which will print you either `True` or `False` e.g. before the if-else block.